# How can i use a closure to log all values in the array with a SetInterval?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, closures

```
function displayValues(values) {
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {     
       setInterval(function() {
          console.log('The item ' + i + ' has value ' + values[i]) //Currently only logs length of array
      }, 500)
    }
}
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
displayValues(array)
```

I encapsulated the SetInterval in a function which currently logs index 0 and value a, but I can never get the rest of the values. Here is my code below. Am I close?

```
function display(values) {

  function getVal(){
    return setInterval(function() {
          console.log('The item ' + i + ' has value ' + values[i])
      }, 500)
  }
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {     
       return getVal()
    }
}
```

Comment: `function getVal(i){` and `return getVal(i)` ... oh, and remove the `return` in the line calling `getVal` - because that will terminate your function after one iteration

Comment: alternatively, for modern browsers ... change `var i` to `let i` in your FIRST code block

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `setTimeout()` rather than `setInterval()`? Using `setInterval()` will continue to log forever rather than once per element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can loop as, var is declared outside setInterval function and by 500ms completes the loops starts completing instead of waiting (async behaviour). So it always takes `i` as length of array i.e `i++` till `i < value.length`

```js
function displayValues(values) {
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    (function(j) {
      setInterval(function() {
        console.log('The item ' + j + ' has value ' + values[j]);
      }, 500);
    })(i);
  }
}
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
displayValues(array)
```

Lets take in an encapsulated way

```js
function display(values) {
  function getVal(j) {
    setInterval(function() {
      console.log('The item ' + j + ' has value ' + values[j]);
    }, 500);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    getVal(i);
  }
}

var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
display(arr);
```

And the above both are same. 2nd snippet says there is an external function named `getVal` and in 1st snippet its just an anonymous function.